# Dynamic table generation in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I dynamically generate an HTML `<table>` with a variable number of rows?

The number of rows will depend on the number of properties that exist within a Javascript object.

```
function showTable(trnum) //number of table rows passed in
{
   // how?
   // $("#elem").foo // #elem - element container for table
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function showTable(trnum) {
    var tableCode = "<table>";
    for (var i=0; i<trnum; i++) {
        tableCode += "<tr>" + "stuff inside each tr ?" + "</tr>";
    }
    tableCode += "</table>";
    $("#elem").append(tableCode);
}
```

Comment: You missed to add the TD tags within rows and its seems the code is also creating an extra ending TR tag. Isn't it?

Comment: Extra ending TR tag should be table tag.

Comment: Indeed, the last tag is a `</table>` ! And he did not specify how he wanted the `<td>` tags to be inserted, that's why I wrote _"stuff inside each tr ?"_ instead.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link. 
[Generating HTML Tables with jQuery](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/linqed/archive/2009/03/04/generating-html-tables-with-jquery.aspx). For demo go [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dJUKd/)

Comment: You left the line numbers in the code in your jsFiddle, and you forgot to set the framework to `jQuery`. Also you didn't call the js function to create the table. I've updated your jsFiddle, you can change your link to [http://jsfiddle.net/dJUKd/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/dJUKd/3/)

Comment: @Sylvain. Thanks for doing so.... :-)) FYI the specified things were already there and demo was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could give this a try:

```
$.createTable = function(trnum)
{
    var reps = new Array(trnum);
    var table = $('<table></table>');
    $.each(reps,function(){ 
        var td    = $('<tr><td> Stuff here </td></tr>');
        table.append(td)     
    }); 
    $('#elem').append(table);
}
```

Calling function:

```
$.createTable(6);
```